# jquery how to change clicked attribute

Tags: jquery

I have code like this:

```
<div id="mtg_card"><a href="#" onclick="someEvent()"><img class="mtg_shop_cart" src="images/shop_cart_green.png" alt="" /></a></div>
```

it's going through loop so I have this same code X times...
all is in one div called rounded-corner, and I wanted to change image in clicked div... I was trying code like this:

```
<script>
$( window ).load(function() {

    $('#rounded-corner #mtg_card').click(function(){
   $(this).$(".mtg_shop_cart").attr("src","http://mgla.pl/images/shop_cart.png");
 });
});

</script>
```

I would be greatful if you could help me with that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you have the same code multiple times, and why do you use two ID's in the selector. You are aware that ID's are unique and that you can't have more than one element with a given ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#rounded-corner #mtg_card').click(function(){
        $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").attr("src","http://mgla.pl/images/shop_cart.png");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This seems about right.
Just remember you can't have multiple elements with same ID in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
$('#rounded-corner #mtg_card').click(function () {
    $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").attr('src', '<source here>');
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7q9fd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false in order for the event handlers to realize the event was received:

```
<script>
$( window ).load(function() {
    $('#rounded-corner #mtg_card').click(function(){
        $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").attr("src","http://mgla.pl/images/shop_cart.png");
        return false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer to improve the quality of it and to help others understand what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

You should replace the id="mtg_card" with a class, and then do this:

```
<div class="mtg_card"><a href="#" onclick="someEvent()"><img class="mtg_shop_cart" src="images/shop_cart_green.png" alt="" /></a></div>

<script>
$( window ).load(function() {

    $('#rounded-corner .mtg_card').click(function(){
   $(this).find(".mtg_shop_cart").attr("src","http://mgla.pl/images/shop_cart.png");
 });
});

</script>
```